# Building bash script to reboot on results of netstat command

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to do a very unique function. I have to run the 'netstat -m' command which will return values. The first line will contain something like:

```
95777/3083/598860 mbufs in use (current/cache/total)
```

So I can do: `netstat -m | grep "mbufs in use"`

For me, the hard part is I need to extract the 3rd number (in this case, 598860). If this number is over 800000 then I need to issue the reboot command. I don't understand regex well enough to extract from the 2nd '/' to the 'space' to get that number, then compare it to 800000 to see if it's greater.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Well, I don't see what's so unique about it... Moreover, that's not a return value. Anyway, what you need is `netstat -m | awk -v FS='[/ ]' '/mbufs in use/ {print $3}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awk approach

```
netstat -m |awk -v FS="[/| ]+" '$0~/mbufs in use/{if($3>800000){print $3}}'
```

Comment: This is great for us because using awk I can get the whole command on one line. Ultimately, here is what I used: `/usr/bin/netstat -m | awk -v FS="[/| ]+" '$0~/mbufs in use/{if($3>800000){system("/sbin/shutdown -r now")} `

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to given answer in comment I would recommend to use [cut](/questions/tagged/cut) command as follows;

```
netstat -m | grep "mbufs in use"|cut -f1 -d' '|cut -f3 -d'/'
```

This will extract 3rd value from 1st field of the result as mentioned by OP.

**Output :**

```
$ netstat -m | grep "mbufs in use"|cut -f1 -d' '|cut -f3 -d'/'

598860
```